# Codeigniter routing is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

hello I need to route that

`/tagi/fotografia,51/` to `/galeria-sztuki-nowosci/?tags=51`

this is only example ofc. My code in routes.php is :

```
$route['tagi/(:any),(\d+)'] = function($id) {
    return 'galeria-sztuki-nowosci/?tags=$id';
};
```

and it's not working.

Comment: Go to application/config/autoload.php and add `'url'` in helpers array, and use this in your function not return : `redirect('galeria-sztuki-nowosci/?tags='.$id, 'location');`

Comment: like this?$route['tagi/(:any),(\d+)'] = function($id) {redirect('galeria-sztuki-nowosci/?tags='.$id, 'location');};

Comment: same problem, i also add url in helper

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Need to add comma in config.php

$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_-,';

next routes.php will be

$route["tagi/([a-z]+),(:any)"] ='old/galleryTags/$2';

And last need to do controller with

public function galleryTags($tags)
    {

```
    if ($tags == "_"): $tags = ""; endif;


    header("Location: /galeria-sztuki-nowosci/?tags=$tags");
}
```

done